# for loop in Python called from bash

Tags: python, bash, for-loop

I am executing a Python (2.6.6) command directly from bash, like this :

```
bash-4.1$ python -c "for i in range(4) : print('a')"
```

which outputs

```
a
a
a
a
```

However, when I add something before the for loop, I get a SyntaxError:

```
bash-4.1$ python -c "myChar = 'a'; for i in range(4) : print(myChar)"
  File "<string>", line 1
    myChar = 'a'; for i in range(4) : print(myChar)
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

no matter what I put before the semicolon. However,

```
bash-4.1$ python -c "i = 1; print i"
```

works just fine.

Any idea of what's happening here?

Comment: Python has significant whitespace, and you cannot put arbitrary statements next to each other using `;`. It's like asking why a C snippet fails to work if you replace some of the curly braces with semicolons.

Comment: To get your command to work you can do something like this `python -c $'myChar=\'a\'\nfor i in range(4): print(myChar)'`

Comment: @Songy Phew, that's ugly.

Comment: Hell yeah, but it gets the job done ;P

Comment: Getting "the job done" using ugly is not in the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): "Beautiful is better than ugly."

Comment: :( `python -c $'myChar="b"\nfor i in range(4): print(myChar)'` I could remove some of the escaping for you. How's the Zen now? :D

Comment: @Songy: bash strings can include return characters, so there is no need to go to heroic lengths to include escaped newlines. `python -c "<return>mychar='a'<return>for i in range(4):<return>  print(myChar)' will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [here document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) if you want to write Python code in a shell script.

```
$ python3.4 <<EOF
myChar = 'a'
for i in range(4):
    print(myChar)
EOF
```

Output:

```
a
a
a
a
```

Read [PEP 0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and [PEP 0020](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) about Python style.

Comment: That's a "here doc", not a "here string". A here string would be `python <<<"..."`, but you don't need that either. Just use a regular string with newline characters inside: `python -c "mychar = 'a'<return>for i ... "`. Here docs (not here strings or direct strings) have the advantage of not needing to escape quotes, etc., but you normally want to disable variable expansion by using `<<"EOF"`